# How do I make a command in cygwin to run Sublime Text?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to mimic the `subl` command in iterm for mac computers in cygwin.

Basically, I want to be able to open a current folder from cygwin by typing `subl .`

I haven't found any good instructions. I know where my .bashrc file is located. I just dont know what to do to create the command `subl` and make it so that the path following `subl` opens with Sublime.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to make an alias and source it from bashrc.

Example

Create a file `~/.bash_aliases` with:

```
alias subl='/cygdrive/c/sublime.exe' #make sure this command is correct for you
```

Now in `~/.bashrc` do:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Log out and log back in, and `subl .` should work

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Before you answered, I found a second way to do it by creating a file via file explorer named subl and writing a script inside of that. Your answer seems to load sublime up a lot quicker though. Thanks again!

Comment: Follow up: This works but keep cygwin locked up until I exit sublime again. What would be the syntax to keep this from happening? In the other way, I simply added a `$1 &`. I'm not sure how to accomplish it using the .bash_aliases because the quotation marks were unnecessary in the other example.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work for cygwin bash, but I would launch it as a nohup: $ nohup /cygdrive/c/sublime.exe &

Comment: `nohup` is probably the better option, but you can make the `&` part of the alias if you want.  Just add the `&` at the end, before the last quote

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want correct behaviour when doing `subl ~`, a simple alias or adding Sublime Text to your `PATH` will not work.

You can use the following bash function instead (put it in your `.bashrc`):

```
function subl {
    cygpath --windows $@ | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe
}
```

Note that when passing paths to `xargs` you need to 1) escape the backslashes, 2) use the `NUL` character as argument delimiter for it to work with paths with spaces.

**Edit**: Use `subl.exe` rather than `sublime_text3.exe` so that it would detach itself from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To open files and use Git tools (commit, rebase, tag, ... messages):

```
#!/bin/bash
# To create in [.babun/]cygwin/usr/local/bin/subl with chmod +x

ARGS=""
while test $# -gt 0
do
  ARGS="$ARGS ${1#/cygdrive/[a-zA-Z]}"; # Remove /cygdrive and disk letter from the path
  shift
done

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe $ARGS
```

https://gist.github.com/cmalard/16c58869319c9a88473ec08cc7989c6b﻿

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add Sublime to your PATH variable. For cygwin, you can:

1. Go to your home directory and verify `.bash_profile` exists with `ls -a`
2. Open `.bash_profile` with something like `vim .bash_profile`
3. add the line `export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3"` (or whatever top level installation folder Sublime is in)
4. Reopen your terminal and use `subl` to verify it works