# git difftool Beyond Compare 4 not diffing local with remote

Tags: git, beyondcompare, git-difftool, beyondcompare4

I am using CYGWIN and Beyond Compare 4 Pro Edition. I have set up the following .gitconfig file:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

After making a small change to a local file, I run the following command in CYGWIN:

```
git difftool
```

Beyond Compare 4 launches correctly but only with the left side in all red. The right side is empty.

I would like this to launch with a simple comparison of my local changes (left) compared to the remote (right).

I was under the assumption that this was the default behavior? Is there another setting I am missing or is this only avaiable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by configuring my .gitconfig file to the following:

```
[difftool "bc3"]
     cmd = \"c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe\" "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$REMOTE"
```

This brings up a diff of the local and remote when doing a `git difftool`

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify [jipot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43723426/5009913) above:

```
git config --system difftool.bc.cmd '"c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe" "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$(cygpath -w $REMOTE)"'
```

Going further, similarly for the mergetool:

```
git config --system mergetool.bc.cmd '"c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe" "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$(cygpath -w $REMOTE)" "$(cygpath -w $BASE)" "$(cygpath -w $MERGED)"'
```

As for the `core.editor`, if you want to use Sublime Text, you need to use an external script `~/git-editor.sh` that contains the following command:

```
cygpath --windows $@ | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe -n -w
```

I modified the above from [Alexander Revo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007140/5009913).

Then add it to your git `core.editor` config:

```
git config --system core.editor "~/git-editor.sh"
```

If you don't use an external script for the editor, git will cause Sublime text to open two files if you attempt to put `$cygpath` in the `core.editor` config as git will append the "wrong path" filename to the end of your `core.editor` setting.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you listed should work correctly with Git for Windows 2.12.1.windows.1 in a Windows command prompt. I haven't tested it with Cygwin.

If you're using a Cygwin provided version of Git, it might help to switch to the Windows version of Git from https://git-scm.com/ instead. In the past, Cygwin's version of Git lagged the official Windows version pretty significantly. To check your version of Git, run "git --version".